# Delete Distinct column and latest date of other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have a table where the primary key is a composite key of ID and date. Is there a way that I can delete a single row where ID matches and the date is the latest date?

I am new to SQL, so I have tried a few things, but I either don't get the results I am looking for or cant get the syntax correct

```
DELETE FROM Master 
WHERE ((Identifier = 'SomeID') 
  AND (EffectiveDate = MAX(EffectiveDate));
```

There are multiple columns with the same ID, but different dates, ie.

```
ID        EffectiveDate
-------------------------
A         '2019-09-18'
A         '2019-09-17'
A         '2019-09-16'
```

Is there a way I can delete only the row with `A | '2019-09-18'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and an updatable CTE:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by effective_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  If you want to limit this to a single `id`, then be sure to include a `where id = 'a'` in either the subquery or outer query.

Answer (score 0):

use row_number()

```
delete from (select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by effectivedate desc) rn from table_name
) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery might get the job done:

```
DELETE FROM Master 
WHERE 
    Identifier = 'SomeID'
    AND EffectiveDate = (
        SELECT MAX(EffectiveDate) FROM Master WHERE Identifier = 'SomeID'
    )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CTE Function to Delete the Row but the below Query will not delete the Record of Max Date of those ID's where Single Record exist against that.

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by effective_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum = 1 and id  in(select distinct id from todelete where seqnum<>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With correlated subquery for all IDs:

```
delete table1
from table1 t1
where t1.EffectiveDate =
(
select max(t2.EffectiveDate)
from table1 t2
where t2.ID = t1.ID
)
```